# Getting MySQL Query to run with variable derived from $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

I've been stuck on this for hours! Please excuse my naivety as I am a newb with programming.

My page runs a number of MySQL UPDATE queries based on some variables. One of the variables is derived from the URL of the current page (which isn't static) so I have to use $_GET to acquire it:

```
$subjvar = $_GET['subj'];
echo $subjvar;
```

This works fine - the URL is e.g. blahblah.php?subj=07EN and the above echoes 07EN with no problems.

However, when the MySQL query tries to run:

```
$insertjavavar = "UPDATE timedb SET $subjvar = '$javavartodb' WHERE week = '$javavaralsotodb' ";
$insertjavavarquery = mysql_query($insertjavavar) or die ("JQuery sucks");
```

it doesn't update the database. It doesn't give me the die message, it just fails silently.

The query doesn't seem to be the problem - if I define $subjvar manually:

```
$subjvar = '07EN';
```

it runs fine, updating the field entitled 07EN with all the relevant data.

So I am completely mystified as to why it won't do so when the variable is defined using $_GET.

I should mention that the MySQL query in question is run based on a JQuery function, and receives its other variables (without any problems, seemingly) from AJAX POSTs.

Please let me know if I've missed anything out and I can provide more info / code as necessary.

Comment: what's your $javavaralsotodb value?

Comment: It's e.g. wk2. One of my JQuery functions acquires the id of a droppable <div> and AJAX POSTs it for use with the MySQL Query.

Comment: could you show us your `$insertjavavar` value before executing query?

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but do know that you need to escape your vars first. Run `mysql_real_escape_string` on those, to prevent SQL injection attacks: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: `echo $insertjavavar;` and show it here

Comment: I get nothing when I try to echo $insertjavavar I'm afraid, whether $subjvar is defined manually or using $_GET. I've tried echo and print_r with no joy.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make are sense at all. Is $subjvar meant to contain the name of a column in the timedb table? Because that is what you seem to be doing. But if its value is 07EN it will blow up, and you would get your die message.

Comment: Hi Philip - yes, $subjvar is designed to be the name of a column. There are 5 columns - id, week, 07EN, 08EN and 09EN. I'm interested in updating the final three of these, so $subjvar is always either 07EN, 08EN or 09EN. If I manually define $subjvar as one of them, it works no problem - it puts whatever is in $javavartodb into the relevant column where week = $javavaralsotodb. However, if I try and define $subjvar based on the URL it fails - silently.

Answer (score 0):

If you echo the query to stdout to see what SQL is getting executed. I suspect it's a syntax error tbh - just take a bit of tweaking around.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's just miss placed quotes 
try to change your code to be like this:

```
$insertjavavar = "UPDATE timedb SET ". $subjvar . " = \"" . $javavartodb . "\" WHERE week = \"" .$javavaralsotodb. "\"";
```

or:

```
$insertjavavar = "UPDATE timedb SET $subjvar = \"$javavartodb\" WHERE week = \"$javavaralsotodb\"";
```

see also: http://id2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

in order to be able to see error reporting
change your php.ini direction
look for **error_reporting** and set the value to be **E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED**

hope its useful

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the value you get into string:

`$subjvar = $_GET['subj'];
 $subjvar = (string)$subjvar;
$insertjavavar = "UPDATE timedb SET $subjvar = '$javavartodb' WHERE week = '$javavaralsotodb' ";
$insertjavavarquery = mysql_query($insertjavavar) or die ("JQuery sucks");`

I hope it helps if not do reply.